# Android Web App breaks on Screen Rotation After Invalid Login

Tags: android, webview, browser-cache

I am making a simple Android app that essentially redirects to a `WebApp`. To do this, I use a `WebView`. I am getting an error "net:::ERR_CACHE_MISS" only when there is a failed login attempt followed by an orientation change. Does anyone know why this could be? I am nearly positive it is not to do with the `WebApp` I am redirecting to.

Code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView myWebView;
String webURL = "omitted";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(webURL);
    }
    else {
        ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    myWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    myWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

In your activity tag, in the AndroidMainfest.xml

Comment: Thank You! This works. Could you explain how this help with caching?